# google seo indexing subdomains

Tags: html, web, seo

Please only answer if you comprehensively know and can elaborate.
**One answer given, waiting for more views**

I see stackoverflow questions are index in google search **immediately.**

I have a domain.( **masoodahmad.com** )

I have a subdomain. **resume.masoodahmad.com**

I have a **link** to resume.masoodahmad.com  in the masoodahmad.com/index.html. 
masoodahmad.com **is visible in google search but** resume.masoodahmad.com **is not**(not by keywords of its contents nor by its name) .

what could be the reason?
what are the things that I need or is there a problem on my end.

if masoodahmad.com/index.html was indexed. it had a link to resume.masoodahmad.com. so resume.masoodahmad.com should be indexed too?

**its not possible that the spider knows about masoodahmad.com/indext.html (which has a link to resume.masoodahmad.com) and not visited or knows about the resume.masoodahmad.com** 
even if crawler didnt visited resume.masoodahmad.com . it does knows about it. so why not in google results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your domain is new you just need to wait that the crawler go there and index your third level... it can take more than two weeks as well.

I suggest you to put inside your root also a robot.txt and at least a title of your page.

Robots.txt example:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

save it as robots.txt and put it in your root folder.

Comment: if masoodahmad.com/index.html was indexed. it had a link to resume.masoodahmad.com. so resume.masoodahmad.com should be indexed too?

Comment: can you give a sample robot.txt?

Comment: nope. Is possible that the spider didn't visited your page or that has not be indexed. There are few rules to follow to improve it. Good use of headings, title, description, robots.txt, sitemap, etc...

Comment: its not possible that the spider knows about masoodahmad.com/indext.html (which has a link to resume.masoodahmad.com)  and not visited or knows about the resume.masoodahmad.com

Comment: Yes is possible instead. A crawler do not visit everything at 100%.

Comment: Improve also your title and not with "site under construction". Put your name, without ".com"

Comment: To check if a spider went to your subdomain register your website to the Google Webmaster tool and monitor it from there. It can take weeks.

Comment: even if crawler didnt visited resume.masoodahmad.com . it does knows about it. so why not in google results?

Comment: because has not been indexed. Even if you submit your urls via sitemap is not 100% sure that all your urls will be indexed.

Comment: ok.if you are sure (as I am a newbie and iam not sure) is there a citation for that?

Comment: Yes sure, Google provide with a very good and deep guide about SEO, Indexing, Crawling, etc...

Comment: ok. thanks +1 for help!

Comment: Please explain why you would disallow all robots?

Comment: I believe you are asking Andrea Turri ?

Comment: I think sarnold pointed about "Disallow: /"

Comment: Hm, ye I just copy paste it very fast from a source. Now is the correct updated, thanks for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try proper  tags to improve chances. The main page only have on  tag.

Comment: You have to wait a while for google to crawl

Comment: Are you sure its only about waiting?